# How to set value to input field

Tags: selenium

Can you please suggest me how can I set value

```html
<input type="text" name="loginAccountName" maxlength="100" value="" id="loginAccountName" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c">
```

I have tried using CSS

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class=textbox ui-input-text ui-body-c]")).sendKeys("qwqweq");
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Can you share surrounding  HTML for which you are trying to send value.

Comment: Element you want to test has an ID, it's easier: `driver.findElement(By.id("loginAccountName")).sendKeys("qwqweq");`. Note that you may also use `.setAttribute("value", "something")` instead of `.sendKeys()`.

Comment: You need single quote around the class attribute `"input[class='textbox ui-input-text ui-body-c']"`

Comment: Second thing is I'm not seeing any `textbox` class in your input tag so it can be  `input[class='ui-input-text ui-body-c']`

Answer (score 1):

To locate the element, you have tried:

```
By.cssSelector("input[class=textbox ui-input-text ui-body-c]")
```

While working with `cssSelector` we have a much convinient way to specify them. Additionally, you need to drop the `textbox` class as it is not a part of the node attributes. Your effective `cssSelector` could have been:

```
By.cssSelector("input.ui-input-text.ui-body-c")
```

But the above mentioned `cssSelector` may not identify an unique element. Instead we will use the `id` or the `name` locator which remains unique through out the `DOM tree` as follows:

- Using `id`:

  ```
  By.cssSelector("input#loginAccountName").sendKeys("qwqweq");
  ```
- Using `name`:

  ```
  By.cssSelector("input[name=loginAccountName]").sendKeys("qwqweq");
  ```